# JHipster Heroku multiple buildpacks causing extra build step

Tags: angular, maven, heroku, npm, jhipster

After deploying a JHipster monolithic application to Heroku successfully, I noticed it uses 2 separate build packs, `heroku/nodejs` and `heroku/java`.

Do we need both? When looking at the build, I see the node build process run twice in single build.

First iteration

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       ......
-----> Installing binaries
       ......
-----> Restoring cache
       ......
-----> Installing dependencies
       ......
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > XXX@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_07560fbb07d9fc840910cfb7cc14060c
       > npm run webpack:prod
```

Second iteration

```
       [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.10.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ XXX ---
       ......
       [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.10.0:npm (npm install) @ XXX ---
       ......
       [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.10.0:npm (webpack build prod) @ XXX ---
       [INFO] Running 'npm run webpack:prod' in /tmp/build_07560fbb07d9fc840910cfb7cc14060c
       ......
```

Can this be setup in the generator to only choose one buildpack? Is it possible to skip the first iteration even though it finds a package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed with 6.10.0 which only sets the java buildpack and leverages maven/gradle to execute node/npm tasks. [See this pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/11715).

If you want to adapt your current application you can remove the bode buildpack and [adapt the build command](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/11715/files#diff-699f1f06607afec46a74e7b44c781427R704) when using gradle (not for maven).